# How to recombine multiple git repos into a single repo and preserve history?

Tags: git

Our team used to have all our code in one repository. We split our code into multiple repositories.  After working with multiple repos for a while, we want to move back to a single repository.

When the code was split into multiple repos, the git history was not moved.
The old single repo is still around but no one is making changes to it.

Is there a way to combine the multiple repos into a single repo and combine the history in the old single repo with the histories in the new repos.

It would be nice to be able to use `git log` or `git blame` on a file and see changes from the old single repo and the newer many repos.

The single repo had a structure like this:

```
monorepo
-moduleA
-moduleB
-moduleC
```

These are the new repos:
`moduleA`
`moduleB`
`moduleC`

Comment: The 3 modules had a single common branch when they were together? Or they were 3 separate branches? If they had a single common branch, did you rewrite history to split them apart into the new repo?

Comment: The 3 modules were in separate directories on the same branch.  The files in each directory were copied into the new repos and commited, no history was copied over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the directories kept their names, you might rebase all those branches.

So.... let's create a local repo that has access to the 4 remotes. `old`, `new1`, `new2` and `new3`. Each has a single branch `main` and **assuming** that the directories contained inside each branch are still mapping fine (the files were not moved) and the first revision from each one of the `new repos/main` is just like the last revision in `old/main`, then you might rebase the branches from the new remotes on top of the old one.

So.... take `new1`.

```
git rebase --onto old/main revision-id-of-first-revision-of-new1-main new1/main
# at this point you should be in DETACHED HEAD, let's create a local branch
git branch main1
```

Do the same for new2 and 3. You should now have 3 branches called `main1`, `main2` and `main3`.

Merge them together into a single branch.... if you like the result, then push that branch as `old/main`

```
git push old HEAD:main
```

Comment: I'm not sure your assumption holds.  In the old monorepo, moduleA has content in the directory moduleA. In the new moduleA repo, moduleA's content is now at the root of the repository. Once everything is combined again moduleA's content will be in the moduleA directory again. This still seems workable, maybe I can add a commit at the beginning of branch main1 moving the content from moduleA to the root. Then add a commit moving the content from the repo root back to the moduleA directory.

Comment: To elaborate, the history could look like this: Last commit in old monorepo -> Move moduleA from moduleA directory to root of repo(first commit on main1 branch) -> rebased commits from the moduleA repo -> Move moduleA directory to root of the repository -> Merge main1 into main

Comment: Might need to run a rewrite of history in the _new_ branches to map to the old directories so that when rebasing everything will be at the right directory (in terms of the _old_ paths).

Comment: I got it to work. Before the rebase:     git checkout -b moduleA    git rm moduleB moduleC    git mv moduleA .    git commit -m "Glue moduleA" After rebasing:      git mv moduleA-files moduleA    git commit -m "Glue moduleA"     To merge back     git merge --no-ff --no-commit moduleA-combined    git checkout HEAD moduleB moduleC    git checkout moduleA-combined moduleA